# free Windows tool to view and edit the UEFI NVRAM boot options variables like Linux EFIBOOTMGR tool

Tags: windows, boot

Using the Linux EFIBOOTMGR tool it is possible to view and edit the boot options variables stored in the UEFI firmware NVRAM.  Is there a similar tool that runs in Windows?  There is a Windows GUI tool called EasyUEFI but it costs $30.

Comment: [Windows equivalent to efibootmgr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44919190/995714)